# Cookies.get('token') returns empty/undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies

While reading a cookies from local device it returns empty only for 'token' where there are other cookies it can easily get them
here is backend code to set cookies

```
let tokenData = {
  id: user._id,
  email: user.email,
  name: user.name
}
const token = await jwt.sign(tokenData, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET!, {
  expiresIn: '1d'
})
const response = NextResponse.json({
  message: "Login successfully",
  success: true
})
response.cookies.set("token", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
})
```

Reading cookies

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getUser = Cookies.get("token")
  console.log(getUser)
}, [])
```

Why can't i read only 'token" this cookie.

Comment: Because of `httpOnly: true`, you do not have access to this cookie using client-side scripting.